# Hubot dosent Answer - Hubot Unix (Shell Adapter)

Tags: linux, node.js, unix, github, hubot

I've been having some problems to start using Hubot. I heard a lot about the tool and I was amused about all the things that I coud do with it. So my first step would install the hubot and see how it works and try to build some solutions.

However I've been trying to install the tool in a simplest way and dosen't work, the tool dosen't answer any comman,  I just want to install in my machine get on the Hubot console (SHELL adapter) and test some scripts.

I followed many tutorials..

- https://hubot.github.com/docs/deploying/unix/
- http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/how-to-install-and-use-hubot-robot-on-ubuntu-machine
  (I'm posting only two because Stack limitation)...

I tried in my machine (Debian) in many Amazon instances (with IAM Amazon.. Ubuntu images).. and always is the same problem, I tried to run some command and dosent work.. Hubot doesnt answer..

```
Hubot> ping
Hubot>
```

I ran in debug mode and the only message printed was:

```
 DEBUG No listeners executed; falling back to catch-all
```

I'm sure that all dependencies are ok, I installed and tested many versions of Nodejs and NPM but still dosent answer..

```
root@test:/opt/hubot# npm -v
2.14.1
root@test:/opt/hubot# nodejs -v
v0.12.7
```

SOMEONE CAN HELPPP??

Answer (score 3):

Looks like You forgot to add "--alias !" to your run command. Run comand should be like this: `... bin/hubot --name "stanley" --alias !`

Answer (score 0):

you need to preface your command with the robots name

```
Hubot> ping
Hubot>
```

should be

```
Hubot> Hubot ping
Hubot> PONG
```